# How effective is creating index on column having two types of values only in dynamodb

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, indexing, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB in my service. In the table, **there is a field called Type.** The Type column contains two types of values, let's say values are X and Y. In the table, 1-2% of records contain value X and the rest contains value Y.

I want to get all the records that have type field value X. To avoid the scan operation, I am thinking of creating a Global secondary index on the field Type.

Does it make sense to create GSI on the field/attribute **Type**?

Any help would be appreciated.